# Why is the Texture Paint layers manager not switching slots

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm on Windows 8.1 (surface pro2), with Blender 2.73a. I reinstalled blender and tested again, uninstalled again and installed latest 2.73a, tested again...

I seem to have followed every step in order to paint textures on my model (plain standard cube).

I can paint! Technically everything is working, but **I cannot switch between the layers by clicking the brush icon in the Texture Paint Manager** (<kbd>N</kbd> - Sidepanel when in texture paint mode). I can even toggle their visibility via the eye icon.

But when I switch via the brush icon (bpy.ops.object.set_active_paint_layer(tex_index=1)), it selects the texture in the properties window, but it doesn't switch the Paint Slots and thus I keep painting on the first layer, no matter where the brush icon displays.

Everything is working when I directly click on another Paint Slot in the left panel, but that's tiring because I have to switch back and forth between "Tools" to select a brush and "Slots" to switch layers.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on or can anyone reproduce that?

- UVs are unwrapped
- GSLS active (when in solid mode also textured solid activated)
- display method texture (next problem: i cannot get f.e. bump map to display in solid mode)
- light in scene
- textures are named
- files saved
- see them in properties
- The Paint Slots on the left are also visible
- blender newly re-installed

A video to look at: (But things seemed to change to this version because I can't get the same results in Object mode with GLSL and Textured Solid - as I said - no bump map rendered)
http://cgcookie.com/archive/using-the-texture-paint-layer-add-on/

Comment: Since 2.72 texture painting was streamlined and the API changed. Bug reports should go to the [tracker](https://developer.blender.org/). You could split 3D Views for the tool shelf and preview. [Example](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/82643).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice and sorry for being off topic.. i didnt know wether it was a bug or me being stupid.

Comment: It is not a bug - but this is something to do with using the Texture Paint Layer addon at the same time as the new feature of Texture Paint Slots. The OP could have uninstalled the add on and then pinned the Slots panel in place in the tool bar and used that only and gotten along fine.